# Should/could a Kubernetes pod process.exit(1) itself or is it better to use liveliness probe?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I have an important service running in Kubernetes.
You can picture it as a dispatcher service which connects to a publisher and dispatch the information to a RabbitMQ queue:

```
[Service1: publisher] -> [Service2: dispatcher] -> [Service3: RabbitMQ]
```

(everything is in the same namespace, there is one replica for each service and they are set as Stateful Sets)

If the connection between `publisher` and `dispatcher` is down, `publisher` will buffer the messages, all good.
However, if the connection between `dispatcher` and `RabbitMQ` is down, the messages will be lost.

Thus, when I lose connection with `RabbitMQ`, I'd like to somehow `process.exit(1)` the dispatcher so it instantly stops receiving messages from `publisher` and then the messages are buffered.

I'm also thinking about doing it in a more "k8s way" by setting up a liveliness probe but I'm afraid this could take some time before it detects it and restart (without "DDoSing" my pod every 1sec). Because to set up this probe, I would have to "listen for disconnect" and if I know I am disconnected, why should I wait for k8s to take action (and lose precious messages) while I could simply kill the service?

I know the question might be a bit vague but I'm also asking for some hints / best practices here. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the design wrt k8s? Are they in different clusters/stateful sets/pods/containers? How many replicas of each?

Comment: Sure, they are all Stateful sets + in the same cluster and namespace + there is only one replica of each (I will update my message).